# R - How to add multiple conditions using mutate and filter

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

I am working with a dataset, and I understand how to setup one condition using mutate and filter, 
but I would like to setup multiple conditions depending of the value of user_location. And also, in the case where the user_location is missing of any country, I would like to setup = "Other".

```
# 1. Some values from the original dataframe
lat = c(-58.3815591, -63.6166720, -58.3815591, -102.5527840, -58.3815591)
lon = c(-34.6036844, -38.4160970, -34.6036844, 23.6345010, -34.6036844)
user_location = c('Buenos Aires, Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires', 'México', 'Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aire')
n = c(88,81,71,29,26)

b = data.frame(lat,lon,user_location,n)


# 2. Filter
#Just for the example:
c_argentina <- c("Argentina","Buenos Aires","Bs As",'Bs Aires','iudad   Aut*noma','San Telmo') 
c_mexico <- c("M*xico","Veracruz")

#For the complete dataset, I will be using filters for 10+ countries
c_peru <- c("Per*","Lima") 
c_brazil <- c('Brazil','Brasil','Brasilia','Rio de Janeiro','Sao Paulo') 
c_chile <- c("Chile","Santiago") 
c_uruguay <- c("Uruguay","Montevideo",'Durazno') 
c_ecuador <- c("Ecuador","Guayaquil") 
c_united_states <- c("USA","Washington","DC","Chicago",'United States','NY','Miami') 
c_canada <- c("Canada","Montreal","Alberta","Ottawa") 

# 3. Create a new column 
# For now, I understand how to setup just one condition.
b <- b %>%
as_tibble() %>% 
subset(user_location %in% c_argentina) %>%
mutate(country = "Argentina") `
```

Comment: "I would like to setup multiple conditions". Such as what conditions? What output are you hoping for?

Comment: @camille An extra column with the country. Let me add the expected result: `lat = c(-58.3815591, -63.6166720, -58.3815591, -102.5527840, -58.3815591, NA)
lon = c(-34.6036844, -38.4160970, -34.6036844, 23.6345010, -34.6036844, NA)
user_location = c('Buenos Aires, Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires', 'México', 'Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aire','London')
n = c(88,81,71,29,26,101)
country = c('Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Argentina', 'México', 'Argentina', 'Other')

result = data.frame(lat,lon,user_location,n,country)`

Comment: @rmn: please add it to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original data

```
lat = c(-58.3815591, -63.6166720, -58.3815591, -102.5527840, -58.3815591)
lon = c(-34.6036844, -38.4160970, -34.6036844, 23.6345010, -34.6036844)
user_location = c('Buenos Aires, Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires', 'México', 'Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aire')
n = c(88,81,71,29,26)

b = data.frame(lat,lon,user_location,n,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Expected results

```
lat = c(-58.3815591, -63.6166720, -58.3815591, -102.5527840, -58.3815591, NA) 
lon = c(-34.6036844, -38.4160970, -34.6036844, 23.6345010, -34.6036844, NA) 
user_location = c('Buenos Aires, Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires', 'México', 'Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aire','London') 
n = c(88,81,71,29,26,101) 
country = c('Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Argentina', 'México', 'Argentina', 'Other') 
result = data.frame(lat,lon,user_location,n,country)
```

Markup the filter

```
c_united_states <- c("USA","Washington","DC","Chicago",'United States','NY','Miami') 
c_argentina <- c("Buenos Aires","Buenos Aire","Argentina") 
c_mexico <- c("México")
```

Solutions

```
library(dplyr)
```

1.Concatenate the matching city with pipe

```
 c1 <- paste0(c_united_states,collapse = "|")
 c2 <- paste0(c_argentina,collapse = "|")
 c3 <- paste0(c_mexico,collapse = "|")
```

2.Create a data frame for the matching city and country name.

```
c_country <- rbind(c(c1,"US"),c(c2,"Argentina"),c(c3,"Mexico")) %>%
data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
```

3.Hardcode all new country name as "Other"

```
b$country <- "Other"
```

4.Using a loop to do the match, as grep/grepl's match criteria can only take one at a time.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(c_country)) {
b$country <- ifelse(grepl(pattern = c_country$X1[i],x = b$user_location),c_country$X2[i],b$country)
}
```

Your final result is as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate all comments that you added each step by step. I am beginning to work with R and this exercise is beyond my current skills.

Comment: np at all. Every awesome R user started from where you are! Hopefully this is helpful. :)